# form submitted when dynamically adding fields with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am dynamically creating form fields using ng-repeat. I have a div with several inputs/selects and when I click an "add" button, they gets duplicated. No problems so far. However, I also want to perform form validation when the submit button is clicked. Right now, I am doing the following to alert users a field is invalid when the submit button is pressed:

```
.ng-submitted select.ng-invalid, .ng-submitted input.ng-invalid {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This works as expected provided I have not dynamically added inputs to the form. If I add new inputs to the form, .ng-submitted gets added to my form element (without submit being pressed) and all the required and invalid inputs turn red. You can see an example of this here: https://plnkr.co/edit/hDe40mBDjw9aDSDoAhe6?p=preview

Not only do I not want the inputs turning red when simply adding elements, I also don't want the form submitting unless someone has hit the submit button. There must be something I don't understand about submit with angular forms and help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: further testing shows that the button element is the problem.

```
<button ng-click="addRow()">add</button>
```

This works fine however:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="addRow()" value="add"/>
```

Not sure why this is though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of the `type` of a button is "submit". So clicking it submits the form. Putting `type="button"` explicitly prevents the form being submitted when the button is clicked.

Comment: Yeah, just realized my dumb mistake. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use form submit you need to use `ng-submit` on form and change button type to `submit`.

```
 <form name="form" ng-submit="addRow()">
    <div>
      <div ng-repeat="row in rows track by row.id">
        <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="row.id" required/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">add</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

There were multiple changes needed in your code. I have fixed them in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/GEWdCo1cQPPEFJcZxT58?p=preview